# Dart version 2.0.0-dev.64.1 incompatible snapshot

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-2

I just installed Dart version 2.0.0-dev.64.1 and when running tests in WebStorm using the Dart VM I get the error:

> Snapshot not compatible with the current VM configuration: the snapshot requires 'release no-strong no-type_checks no-asserts no-error_on_bad_type no-error_on_bad_override no-sync_async no-reify_generic_functio' but the VM has 'release strong no-type_checks no-asserts no-error_on_bad_type no-error_on_bad_override sync_async reify_generic_functions use_field_guards use_osr x64-win'
>   Isolate creation failed

I did not have this problem with V2.0.0-dev.63.0.

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: I guess you just need to switch to an older Dart version and wait until a newer one comes out.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Webstorm is running run the pub snapshot from the SDK at `bin/snapshots/pub.dart.snapshot` however it doesn't seem to run with the default configuration of the VM in this build (there's a `pub2.dart.snapshot` in the same folder which does work).

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33577#issuecomment-399521736) this is a temporary issue because this version ships Dart2-enabled VM but the `pub` snapshot is not v2. Sounds like the next dev version will correct this.

So for now your best bet is to roll back to an earlier dev build, and then try again when the next one is available.